# How do I host my portfolio website on GitHub?

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, readme

I am trying to host my website on GitHub.

It consists of multiple HTML files (`homepage.html`, `projectpage.html`, `images` folder etc.) and a CSS file. However, when I publish it, only the README is shown and not my HTML web pages.

How do I host my website on GitHub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/):

1. Upload all files to GitHub repository. Name the homepage `index.html`
2. In the top horizontal bar, click <kbd>Settings</kbd>
3. Click on <kbd>Pages</kbd> in the sidebar
4. Under **Branch**, click the dropdown which currently says <kbd>None ▼</kbd> and click <kbd>main</kbd> or <kbd>master</kbd>
5. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

Your site is now published at `username.github.io/repo`.

---

Using [Vercel's free plan](https://vercel.com/pricing) which gives you a customisable subdomain:

1. Upload all files to GitHub repository. Name the homepage `index.html`
2. [Sign up to Vercel for free](https://vercel.com/signup) using your GitHub account
3. Create a [new deploy](https://vercel.com/new)
4. Under **Import Git Repository**, click <kbd>Import</kbd> on the repository you just created
5. Edit the **Project Name** to whatever you wish
6. Click <kbd>Deploy</kbd>

Vercel will start building your site. It will be hosted at `projectname.vercel.app`